# interrupt a boost thread after a certain amount of time

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I would like to interrupt a boost thread after a certain amount of time.

The control flow I have is I have a main thread. 
In the main thread I do :

```
int main() {
    boost::thread t(my_func);
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(60));
    t.interrupt();
    t.join();

    return 0;
}

void my func() {

    try {
        // do something that takes a time greater than sleep time
        boost::this_thread::interruption_point();
    }

    catch (boost::thread_interrupted &) {
        printf("the spawned thread is exiting);
    }
}
```

I am trying this but for some reason when the sleep function is called, the interruption point is not being caught. And even when I take away the sleep function, the catch message is not being displayed.

How would your answer change if the main function was a thread running on another thread?

Comment: Are you sure that it is not interrupted? I tested it; it is interrupted and the catch message displayed...

Comment: [format your code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40685750/revisions); Code is for humans to read. Especially if you think about posting it on a Q&A site.

Comment: I would not use force termination API for BAU functionality and rather have added a flag (if thread is doing an endless cycle of work items) or a marker message (if thread is processing data from a queue), or both.

Comment: so if in my func(), there was an infinite loop?, how would I stop it, after a time duration?